# NHibernate MVVM Session Best Practice

Tags: nhibernate, oop, mvvm

What is the best place to store the NHibernate session if we only need one?

In the main windows view model?
In the app?
In the DataAccess Class?

Comment: You probably don't need only one session for your whole app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read Oren Eini's MSDN article on [Building a Desktop To-Do application with NHibernate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx). He goes into detail about creating and managing the lifetime of an NHibernate session, as well as two-way databinding and propagating entity changes.

I believe he's using some variant of MVP or MVVM in his examples, though he doesn't mention it by name.